# Combine two array in PHP, but not using PHP array_combine()

Tags: php

I have two array like below having same length:

```
$arr1 = array(array(0), array(1), array(2), array(3), array(4), array(5));
$arr2 = array(array(6), array(7), array(8), array(9), array(10), array(11));
```

I need the output like this:

```
array(array(0,6), array(1, 7), array(2, 8), array(3, 9), array(4, 10), array(5, 11));
```

How to do this job. Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`array_map`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$arr1 = array(array(0), array(1), array(2), array(3), array(4), array(5));
$arr2 = array(array(6), array(7), array(8), array(9), array(10), array(11));

$result = array_map(function ($a, $b) {
    return array($a[0], $b[0]);
}, $arr1, $arr2);

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$len = count($arr1);
$arr = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
  $arr[i] = array($arr1[$i], $arr2[$i]);
}
```

not using any special functions.